# ¿Por que no se compila de forma que se pueda ejecutar mi archivo en apache netbeans IDE 18?

Tags: java

¿Por que no se compila de forma que se pueda ejecutar mi archivo en apache netbeans IDE 18?

Mi código es este:

```java
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 */

package com.mycompany.mavenproject15;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author usuario
 */
public class Mavenproject15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Example");
        int count=0;
        frame.setTitle("Count: "+(count));
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        while(true){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            frame.setTitle("Count: "+(count));
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Y cuando lo abro se muestra la ventana como debe ser con la cuenta hacia adelante medida en segundos:

https://anonfiles.com/g755bd73zd/bandicam_2023_08_07_15_22_56_762_mp4

Pero cuando lo compilo, aparece el archivo.jar, pero al hacerle click no se ejecuta, tampoco con la cmd ¿Qué podría hacer?

Comment: Me aparece: `no hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en mavenproject15-1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar`

Comment: `C:\Users\usuario\Downloads\jar1>java -jar mavenproject15.jar
no hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en mavenproject15.jar

C:\Users\usuario\Downloads\jar1>`

Comment: Eso hice en varios proyectos del mavenproject4 al mavenproject12 y segui con el mavenproject15 y el mavenproject16, pero editarlos y compilarlos en un proyecto nuevo no basta o eso creo...

Comment: que **ide** estás usando? porque maven?

Comment: ¿Como se ve eso?

Comment: Creo que el IDE 18 porque es apache netbeans IDE 18

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que se solucionó de momento al cambiar de proyecto y eligiendo el java Ant en vez del java Maven...

Answer (score -1):

Hoy nos toca aprender a los dos:

A la hora de ejecutar un **jar** hecho con **Maven** tenemos que hacer una ligera modificación.

- ejecutar con:

  java -jar mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

  // para que esto funcione, tenemos que abrir el "jar", ir a la carpeta
  // META-INF y editar el archivo MANIFIEST.MF, solo le debemos agregar
  // una linea: Main-Class: com.mycompany.mavenproject1.Mavenproject1
  // (ojo, tiene que quedar una linea en blanco abajo, no modificar)
  // salvamos el archivo, nos pide actualizar, aceptamos y ejecutamos

PD: en "com.mycompany.mavenproject1.Mavenproject1" tienes que reemplazar los nombres, son la ruta y nombre de tu clase principal.

Más info [acá](https://www.hermanbarrantes.dev/jar-ejecutable-con-maven/)